# Excel: Nested IF statement if all condition are true return all true values

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation, nested-if

I want to return multiple values for all the statements executed true. I am using the following formula:

```
=IF(
AND(I4=1,J4=1),"2G",
IF(
AND(Q4=1,V4=1),"3G",
IF(
AND(AC4=1,AG4=1),"4G",
"Other")))
```

However this is returning the first true value from the nested `IF`. I want to return all three values, 2G 3G 4G, if all are true. Something like `concatenated` result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to not get "2G3G4G" and olso to get the "other" if none is true, I suggest something like this:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("     "," ",IF(AND(I4=1,J4=1)," 2G"," "),1)," ",IF(AND(Q4=1,V4=1),"3G "," "),3)," ",IF(AND(AC4=1,AG4=1),"4G"," "),5),"     ","other"))
```

if you have any questions, just ask ;)

**EDIT**:

For Questions which are changing while they are answered I'll provide some "general" code.

If you want to get all solutions lined up you can use this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF([C_1],[E_1]&" ","  ")&IF([C_2],[E_2]&" ","  ")&...&IF([C_n],[E_n],"  "),REPT("  ",[TC]),[NS]))," ",[ND]),[SR]," ")
```

- `[C_1]`,`[C_2]`,...,`[C_n]` : the conditions for each different expression
- `[E_1]`,`[E_2]`,...,`[E_n]` : the expresions itself
- `[TC]` : the total count of all `IF`s in this formula
- `[NS]` : the expresion if no solution is true
- `[ND]` : the new delimeter you want
- `[SR]` : the used "space replacement"

Note: For this solution you can't use expressions which hold spaces. Just replace them with a symbol you are not using like underscore. (An expression like `"Exp. 1"` will be `"Exp._1"`) This will be changed back at the end via the `[SR]`.

So your solution would look like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(OR(I4=1,J4=1),"2G ","  ")&IF(AND(Q4=1,V4=1),"3G ","  ")&IF(AND(AC4=1,AG4=1),"4G","  "),REPT("  ",3),"other"))," ","/"),[SR]," ")
```

Because your expressions do not contain spaces, the `[SR]`-part can be skipped:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(OR(I4=1,J4=1),"2G ","  ")&IF(AND(Q4=1,V4=1),"3G ","  ")&IF(AND(AC4=1,AG4=1),"4G","  "),REPT("  ",3),"other"))," ","/")
```

If you still have any questions, just ask.

Comment: A combination of yours and @BruceWayne makes it a little shorter; `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(AND(I4=J1,J4=1),"2G"," ") & IF(AND(Q4=1,V4=1)," 3G"," ") & IF(AND(AC4=1,AG4=1)," 4G"," "),"   ","OTHER"))`  If there are 3 spaces returned `OTHER` is substituted.

Comment: @Dirk I want to insert "2G" only once but if I check in one if it checks for both conditions to be true. How can I split the if statement to check for each but not add the text for 2G?

Comment: do you mean `OR(I4=1,J4=1)`?

Comment: @ScottCraner but false/false/true would return "other4G"... But `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(OR(I4=J1,J4=1),"2G"," ") & IF(AND(Q4=1,V4=1)," 3G"," ") & IF(AND(AC4=1,AG4=1)," 4G"," ")," ","other"))` with 2 spaces if not 4G and replacing 4 spaces would do it... ;)

Comment: Yes, I can see it.  That was the only combination I did not try.

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but pls stop changing the question or there will never be an end to this...

Answer (score 3):

You have a single `If()` formula, so it's going to stop as soon as the first TRUE is found.  Instead, just concatenate them:

`=If(And(I4=1,J4=1),"2G","") & if(and(q4=1,v4=1),"3G","") & if(and(ac4=1,ag4=1),"4G","")`

edit: Just realized this could leave you with a cell that says "2G3G4G", which I assume isn't quite what you want. Just add a comma separator if needed.

edit2: Per your comment, you may want this:

`=If(Or(I4=1,J4=1),"2G","") & if(Or(q4=1,v4=1),"3G","") & if(Or(ac4=1,ag4=1),"4G","")`

This will check if `I4=J1` **or** `J4=1`. If either of those are `1`, it'll return "2G".  Same with `Q4` and `V4`, if either one are `1`, it'll return "3G".

Comment: Dangnabbit, you got one faster than me.

Comment: @ScottCraner - It was bound to finally happen! Now you know how I feel sometimes :P

Comment: @BruceWayne if I want to split checking for each cell instead, like `If(And(I4=J1),"2G","")&If(And(J4=1),"2G","")`, is this still valid? I want to insert "2G" only once but if I check in one `if` it checks for both conditions to be true

Comment: @Sarah - Sorry, can you explain what you mean? You don't need `And()` if you're just comparing one value. So you can do `If(I4=J1,"2G","") & If(J4=1,"2G","") `.  What do you mean "...but if I check in one If it checks for both conditions to be true"?

Comment: Change the `AND` to `OR`

Comment: @BruceWayne perfect. if I add `/` can I control not to have it at the start of the value?